# ListPlot does not recognize my list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have created a list in Mathematica and for some reason it does not want to Plot my list in pairs {x1,y1}, but instead does {y1,y2} even though I partitioned the list to make it in the correct format. Here is the code:

```
Dynamic[h = w[1.1][[All, 2]] + w[2.1][[All, 2]] + w[3.1][[All, 2]] + 
   w[4.1][[All, 2]] + w[5.1][[All, 2]] + w[6.1][[All, 2]] + w[7.1][[All, 2]] + 
   w[8.1][[All, 2]] + w[9.1][[All, 2]] + w[10.1][[All, 2]]]
k = Table[l + Pi/50, {l, -Pi/50, 49 Pi/50, Pi/50}]
Dynamic[List[p = Riffle[k, h/g]]]
Dynamic[Partition[p, 2]]
Dynamic[ListPlot[p]]
```

The first line takes previously made lists and adds the value of their second column -> (x1, y1) and (x2,y2) returns y3 where y3 = y1+y2. Then a new table from 0 to Pi is created. Then a new list is made, p, with riffle to make x-values go from 0 to Pi and y values are the values from table h. Then the values are partitioned into pairs (x1,y1). Finally, the list should be plotted.  But again, Mathematica does (y1,y2,...) and not in pairs.

Little help? Thanks.

g is a constant between 1 and 10. Below is Full Form p.

```
List[0,1.`,Times[Rational[1,50],Pi],1.`,Times[Rational[1,25],Pi],0.7507598383409988`,Times[Rational[3,50],Pi],0.7507598383409988`,Times[Rational[2,25],Pi],0.7507598383409988`,Times[Rational[1,10],Pi],0.7507598383409988`,Times[Rational[3,25],Pi],0.7507598383409988`,Times[Rational[7,50],Pi],0.7507598383409988`,Times[Rational[4,25],Pi],0.7507598383409988`,Times[Rational[9,50],Pi],0.7507598383409988`,Times[Rational[1,5],Pi],0.7515548444052627`,Times[Rational[11,50],Pi],0.7599302324995563`,Times[Rational[6,25],Pi],0.7691783335090264`,Times[Rational[13,50],Pi],0.779262649404044`,Times[Rational[7,25],Pi],0.7901433819968573`,Times[Rational[3,10],Pi],0.8017775900068562`,Times[Rational[8,25],Pi],0.8141193585301891`,Times[Rational[17,50],Pi],0.8271199802449125`,Times[Rational[9,25],Pi],0.8407281476365374`,Times[Rational[19,50],Pi],0.8548901554853492`,Times[Rational[2,5],Pi],0.8695501128163745`,Times[Rational[21,50],Pi],0.8868534924648825`,Times[Rational[11,25],Pi],0.9050207506466612`,Times[Rational[23,50],Pi],0.9235628485337459`,Times[Rational[12,25],Pi],0.9424066089368552`,Times[Rational[1,2],Pi],0.9614776641425731`,Times[Rational[13,25],Pi],0.9807007494087392`,Times[Rational[27,50],Pi],1.`,Times[Rational[14,25],Pi],1.0192992505912608`,Times[Rational[29,50],Pi],1.0385223358574267`,Times[Rational[3,5],Pi],1.0575933910631448`,Times[Rational[31,50],Pi],1.076437151466254`,Times[Rational[16,25],Pi],1.0949792493533388`,Times[Rational[33,50],Pi],1.1131465075351175`,Times[Rational[17,25],Pi],1.1115136239813286`,Times[Rational[7,10],Pi],1.126173581312354`,Times[Rational[18,25],Pi],1.140335589161166`,Times[Rational[37,50],Pi],1.1539437565527906`,Times[Rational[19,25],Pi],1.166944378267514`,Times[Rational[39,50],Pi],1.1792861467908469`,Times[Rational[4,5],Pi],1.1909203548008458`,Times[Rational[41,50],Pi],1.201801087393659`,Times[Rational[21,25],Pi],1.2118854032886768`,Times[Rational[43,50],Pi],1.2211335042981468`,Times[Rational[22,25],Pi],1.2295088923924404`,Times[Rational[9,10],Pi],1.`,Times[Rational[23,25],Pi],1.`,Times[Rational[47,50],Pi],1.`,Times[Rational[24,25],Pi],1.`,Times[Rational[49,50],Pi],1.`,Pi,1.`]
```

Comment: What is `g`? In any case not possible to answer without seeing `p`. Please evaluate `FullForm[p]` and add it to the question.

Comment: Using the definition of `p` that you just added `ListPlot[p]` works in version 7 on Windows: http://i.stack.imgur.com/toApn.png

Comment: The image just provided by Mr. Wizard is my problem. The values of Pi should be x-axis while the numerical values should be y values.

Comment: You are plotting `p` not the `Partition`ed expression.

Answer (score 2):

You are plotting `p` not the `Partition`ed expression. Merge the last two lines to read `Dynamic[ListPlot[Partition[p,2]]]` and it should work. You might need to `Reverse` each row so the $y$ values are second:

```
Dynamic[ListPlot[Reverse/@ Partition[p,2]]]
```